# How can I find HTML line number In chrome devtool? Is there any way to see line number like the way it looks for css in the chrome devtool?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I want to see the HTML line number here as the CSS line is shown in the dev tool. I give a link below to better understand.

Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt9DQ.png

Comment: You can't do it because  elements can be created dynamically by the code

Answer (score 0):

You can view the line number of **HTML** codes by right clicking on the page then **view page source**.

If you want to check the line number for a **CSS** file, click on the CSS file link then copy the code and use an online tool for "Unminify-ing" the code.

I have tried this website https://unminify.com/ and it worked well.